# Vector of elements not being updated within loop

Tags: r

logically this code should make sense, I'm primarily a python programmer but I'm unsure why this is not working. It is not returning any errors. What I want is for this vector of primarily zeros to be changed to a vector of only 1's and -1's (hence using the sample function). My issue is that the values of the vector are not being updated, they are just staying as 0 and I'm not sure why.

```
Y = numeric(100)

for (i in 100){
  x <- sample(1:2, 1)
  if (x == 2){
    Y[i] = 1
  }
  else{
    Y[i] = -1
  }
}
```

I've also changed the Y[i] = 1 to Y[i] <- 1 but this has not helped. I also know that x is either 1 or 2 because I test it manually using x == 2...etc

The only other issue I could think of is that x is an integer while the numbers sample returns are not but per checking this: (Note that x = 2L after the loop exited)

```
> typeof(x)
[1] "integer"
> typeof(2)
[1] "double"
> x == 2
[1] TRUE
```

I don't think it is the problem.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the loop is just run once i.e. the last iteration.  It did change in the output vector `Y`

```
tail(Y)
#[1]  0  0  0  0  0 -1
```

Instead it would be `1:100`

```
for(i in 1:100)
```

The second issue raised is with the `typeof` 'x'.  Here, we are `sample`ing an `integer` with `1:2` instead of a numeric vector and that returns the same `type` as the input.  According to `?':'`

> For numeric arguments, a numeric vector. This will be of type integer if from is integer-valued and the result is representable in the R integer type, otherwise of type "double"

```
typeof(1:2)
#[1] "integer"
typeof(c(1, 2))
#[1] "double"
```

Another option if it is a range (`:`) is to wrap with `as.numeric`

```
for (i in 1:100){
  x <- sample(as.numeric(1:2), 1)
  if (x == 2){
    Y[i] = 1
  }
  else{
    Y[i] = -1
  }
}
```

check the type

```
typeof(Y)
#[1] "double"
typeof(x)
#[1] "double"
```

Comment: oh my god... something so simple... thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Also, R is a vectorized language so this:

```
x<-sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE)
Y<-ifelse(x==2, 1, -1)
```

will run about 1000 times faster than your loop.